# How to get the parameter value and assign to agent in source block

Tags: anylogic

I have an agent with parameters `AccountNo`, `start date`,`end_date` ,`Value`,`type_of_account`,`cycle_time`.
For `AccountNo` I have created a custom distribution based on the actual data. So when an agent is generated at source block it will be assigned an `AccountNo` value. Now before agent leaves source block i want to update other parameter from the SQL table
SQL table has `AccountNo` , `Value,type_of_account`, `Cycle_time` fields.
On exit at source I want to update the agent parameters as below:

1. `agent.start_date=date()`
2. `agent.end_date=  agent.start_date+ cycle_time` (from SQL table for same agent based on same account no)
3. `agent.type_of_acount=type_of_account` (from sql table with corresponding value based on same account No)
   How I can assign the parameter values from SQL table? I tried
   writing query to get the value from db.

.

```
 ((MyAgent1)agent).start_time=date();

  double a= ((MyAgent1)agent).actno;

  double b = selectFirstValue(false, double.class, "SELECT cycle_time FROM sheet1 WHERE actno = a;");
```

It is throwing error

> user lacks privilege or object not found

is there a good way to update parameter values ?

Comment: Do you have proper access to your SQL database? Can you pull any data? Share some details on how you connect to it.

Comment: Finally I solved it . Thanks !!!